# Multi-Dimensional Arrays from multiple selector in multi-row form

Tags: php, arrays

I want to build a form with multiple (unknown number) of rows, and eventually insert that data into a database. However, one of my input fields is multiple select, which messes up the arrays.

Current (simplified) html code:

```
<form name="testform" action="testarray.php" method="post">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><label>formdata</label></td>
    <td><select name="formdata[][]" multiple="multiple">
        <option> </option>
        <option value="item1">Item 1</option>
        <option value="item2">Item 2</option>
        <option value="item3">Item 3</option>
    </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label>formdata</label></td>
    <td><select name="formdata[][]" multiple="multiple">
        <option> </option>
        <option value="item1">Item 1</option>
        <option value="item2">Item 2</option>
        <option value="item3">Item 3</option>
    </select></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and if I select item2 on the first input, and select item2 & item3 on the second input, then simply print the array on the action page `print_r($_POST['formdata']);` than the array looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => item2 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => item2 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => item3 ) )
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => item2 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => item2 [1] => item3))
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is working

```
<?php
$i=0;
 ?>

<form name="testform" action="testarray.php" method="get">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><label>formdata</label></td>
    <td><select name="formdata[<?php echo $i++ ?>][]" multiple="multiple">
        <option> </option>
        <option value="item1">Item 1</option>
        <option value="item2">Item 2</option>
        <option value="item3">Item 3</option>
    </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label>formdata</label></td>
    <td><select name="formdata[<?php echo $i++ ?>][]" multiple="multiple">
        <option> </option>
        <option value="item1">Item 1</option>
        <option value="item2">Item 2</option>
        <option value="item3">Item 3</option>
    </select></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you but no, something is missing because the print_r output still loops the posted data into one array - `Array([]=>Array([0]=>item1[1]=>item2[2]=>item3))` and no matter how I configure your solution (using just `echo $i` or even 0 in the first select, all `i++` get bulked together into a single array.